# Why does my URL appear with #sthash.RXOAdGce.dpbs after it?

Tags: url

I have set up a subdomain which for some reason attaches #sthash.RXOAdGce.dpbs to the end of the URL making it look  like this: `<http://info.example.com/#sthash.gmiCS9nc.dpbs>`.

I am wondering why this happens and how I can get rid of it.

As a bit of background info on things, the subdomain was set in cPanel on 1 server and an 'A' record set on a different server to redirect to the subdomain when the original site is eventually disabled.

Comment: when i open that url i dont get that hash, usually it would be generated by some clientside script on the target url, maybe your pc is hijacked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [Google Group posting](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/blogger/4supWL_oPpI), it looks like adding Share This to your website will do this.

> Have you added the ShareThis Gadget to your site? If so that is
>   causing the issue. You'll need to contact ShareThis support to find
>   out how to disable the URL changes
>
> Well yes! Thank you! I just contacted with sharethis contact team!

Answer (score 1):

Add `shorten:false` and it will not append the hash.

`<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({ doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false , shorten:false});</script>`